# Xamarin.Forms - CollectionView and TabbedPage in one view

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a Xamarin Forms app, where I have a CollectionView of Frames. What I want to add now in this view is a TabbedPage, so that the screen in split in half (using Grid) and the left side has the CollectionView and the right side has the TabbedPage.

I tried to create a TabbedPage in a separate xaml file and then add that to my MainPage (where the CollectionView is as well), inside the grid to set its location, but I get the error that this is not possible. Only ContentViews can be set like this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can use a [TabView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview) from the Xamarin Community Toolkit. There is an example with a TabView inside a Grid

Comment: use a FlyoutPage to do this

Comment: The TabView solution works amazing. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Juan Sturla, the solution was to use the Xamarin Community Toolkit, that can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview